# Oracle - Removing trailing characters from a string using a regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I would like to remove trailing characters from a string using an Oracle regular expression.

My data looks like this:

```
TDC Supervisor #
TDC Supervisor ##
TDC Supervisor ###
Store Manager - 1
Store Manager - 2
Store Manager - 3
Stockroom Clerk Flexi 100 Hrs
Sales Consultant Flexi 120 Hrs
Service Desk Consultant (5 Day)
Secretary
```

I would like to get rid of the trailing `#` and `- 1`, but not the `120 Hrs` and the `5 Day`. Is there a way to do this using an Oracle regular expression. Not sure whether I should use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` or `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

So basically I would like to do a distinct that returns:

```
TDC Supervisor
Store Manager
Stockroom Clerk Flexi 100 Hrs
Sales Consultant Flexi 120 Hrs
Service Desk Consultant (5 Day)
Secretary
```

Comment: so you want to remove the duplicates also.

Comment: Removing the trailing characters is done in order to get less distinct results yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashes at the end are removed with `#+$` (`#` for hash, `+` for one or more, `$` for end of string)

The numbers are removed with `- *\d+$` (`-` for minus, `*` for zero or more spaces, `\d+` for one or more digit.

You can combine both with parens: `(#+$)|(- *\d+$)`.

Zero or more spaces are removed with `*` (or `\s*` to catch other whitespace like tabs etc), so the final regular expression looks like `\s*(#+$)|(-\s*\d+$)`.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn VARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('TDC Supervisor #');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('TDC Supervisor ##');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('TDC Supervisor ###');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Store Manager - 1');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Store Manager - 2');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Store Manager - 3');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Stockroom Clerk Flexi 100 Hrs');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Sales Consultant Flexi 120 Hrs');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Service Desk Consultant (5 Day)');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Secretary');

select distinct regexp_replace(mycolumn,'\s*(#+$)|(-\s*\d+$)') 
  from mytable;

Service Desk Consultant (5 Day)
Store Manager
TDC Supervisor 
Secretary
Sales Consultant Flexi 120 Hrs
Stockroom Clerk Flexi 100 Hrs
```

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff's `\s` are safer than my ` `, they catch tabs and other whitespace. And I forgot the space before the hashes. +1 to Egor.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_replace(string, '\s*(-\s*\d+|#+)$')`
[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faa75/1)